# JPA Specification to filter entries based on a key in the jsonb map

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have an entity as follows:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonbType.class)
})
public class Entity extends BasePersistableEntity<String> implements Serializable {

    public static final String FIELD_NAME_SERVICES = "services";
    public static final String FIELD_NAME_ORG_ID = "orgId";

    @Column
    public String orgId;

    @Column
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    public Map<String, String> services;
}
```

I want to write a query to fetch all the entities from a Postgres database that belong to an `orgId` and has a `service` in its services map.

For example something like,

```
select * from Entity where entity.ordId='abc' and 'xyz' in entity.services.keyset();
```

Currently, I have written the solution as follows:

```
@Override
public List<Entity> getEntitiesWithOrgIdAndService(String orgId, String service) {
    return entityRepository.findEntityByOrgId(orgId).stream()
              .filter(entity -> entity.services.containsKey(service)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Instead of this, I would like to filter it while getting it from the DB. How can I use JPA specification to do so?

Something like as follows:

```
@Override
public List<Proxy> getEntitiesWithOrgIdAndService(String orgId, String service) {
     return proxyRepository.findAll(getSpecificationForEntity(orgId, service));
}

private Specification<Proxy> getSpecificationForProxyForEntity(String orgId, String service) {
     return (Specification<Proxy>) (root, query, builder) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            Predicate orgIdPredicate =
                    builder.equal(root.get(Entity.FIELD_NAME_ORG_ID), orgId);
            // FIX NEEDED 
            /* Predicate servicePredicate =
                    builder.equal(builder.function("jsonb_extract_path_text",
                            String.class, root.<String>get(Entity.FIELD_NAME_SERVICES), service); */
            Predicate orgIdServicePredicate = builder.and(orgIdPredicate, servicePredicate);
            predicates.add(orgIdServicePredicate);
            return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        };
}
```

Comment: What does not work with the function jsonb_extract_path_text? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli was getting the error `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function jsonb_extract_path_text(jsonb) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. `
I could solve it as follows but did not understand how does `jsonb_extract_path_text` work.

Answer (score 0):

The below change solved the issue for me.

```
Predicate servicePredicate =
                    builder.equal(builder.function(Constants.FUNCTION_JSONB_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT,
                            String.class, root.<String>get(Proxy.FIELD_NAME_SERVICES),
                            builder.literal(service)), String.valueOf(true));
```